# Why can Scala and sbt compile this code?

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt, implicit

**Example of Scala Worksheet**

```
case class Test(name: String)

case class TestMapped(name: String,
                      otherProperty: String)

protected implicit def toTestMapped(test: Test): TestMapped = {
  TestMapped(name = test.name,
             otherProperty = test.otherProperty)
}

val test = Test(name = "bug")
val testMapped = toTestMapped(test)
```

Why can Scala and sbt compile this code, if "otherProperty" does not exists in class Test ? **This code ends in a critical runtime error:  java.lang.StackOverflowError**

However, if you remove "implicit" of toTestMapped method, or change "otherProperty" by other name, this code does not compile.

I'm using Scala 2.12.4.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, by defining `implicit def toTestMapped` you created an implicit conversion from `Test` to `TestMapped`.

Secondly, in `test.otherProperty`. Since test is a `Test` object and doesn't have `otherProperty`, scala will lookup the implicit conversions in scope and find `toTestMapped` that will typecheck. Now `test.otherProperty` can be seen as `toTestMapped(test).otherProperty`, in which toTestMapped(test) will call itself indefinitely and you end up with stackoverflow exception.

Now if you remove the implicit, `test.otherProperty` would not compile because the `Test` object doesn't have val or def `otherProperty` and compiler can't find any implicit conversion.
Similarly, if you rename `otherProperty` in either place, compiler won't be able to find the name. However if you replace all occurences of `otherProperty` you end up with the same issue